# How to correctly switch between pages with a single button using useNavigate or a simpler alternative?

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

I'm developing a React application and I'm trying to implement a feature where I can toggle between two different pages using a single button. I'm using the useNavigate hook from React Router to handle the page navigation.

Here's a simplified example of the code I'm using:

My main.tsx

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <HomePage />,
  },
  {
    path: "/edit",
    element: <EditPage />,
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

My SideButton.tsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./style.css";

const SideButton = () => {
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (!editMode) {
      navigate("/");
    } else {
      navigate("/edit");
    }
    setEditMode((prevEditMode) => !prevEditMode);
  };

  return (
    <div className="side-button-container" onClick={handleClick}>
      {!editMode ? "Home" : "Edit"}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SideButton;
```

In this code, I use the editMode state to control which page should be displayed when the button is clicked. When the button is clicked, the handleClick function is called, toggling the editMode state and navigating to the corresponding page using navigate.

However, I'm experiencing issues with the page transition. Sometimes, the transition works correctly, but other times it seems like the page is not updated properly or not rendered correctly.

I would like to know how I can make the transition between pages more consistent and ensure that the page is rendered correctly when toggling between them using a single button. Is there a simpler or more appropriate way to achieve this transition using useNavigate or any other approach that can help me solve this issue?

Thank you in advance for any help!

*** Bug example ***

Note that sometimes I'm on the Home page and when I click, it goes back to the Home page again.
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

It's only in one file to make things easier.

I assume you were using the `Sidebutton` in `Home` and in `Edit`, so when you changed the route the component state was reset. The Sidebutton must stay outside the routes.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Route, RouterProvider, Routes, createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

//-------------------- SideButton.js --------------------
import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const SideButton = () => {
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => {

    const newEditModeValue = !editMode; //  change the value before checking

    if (newEditModeValue) {
      navigate("/edit");
    } else {
      navigate("/");
    }
    setEditMode(newEditModeValue);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ border: "3px solid black", marginTop: "20px" }} className="side-button-container" onClick={handleClick}>
      {editMode ? "Go to Home" : "Go To Edit"}
    </div>
  );
};

//---------------- Root.js -------------------------
const Root = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/edit" element={<Edit />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
      <SideButton />  {/*  SideButton outside the routes*/}
    </div>
  )
}

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: "*", Component: Root }, //  all paths to Root
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

//---------------------- Home.js -------------------------
const Home = () => {
  return <div>HOME PAGE
  </div>
}

//---------------------- Edit.js -------------------------
const Edit = () => {
  return <div>EDIT PAGE
  </div>
}
```